# jsfl: accessing a symbol to animate inside it

Tags: jsfl

I have several symbols on the stage, rectangles and a circle. 
[symbols on stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3dnf.jpg)
I want to get into the circle and animate the symbols in it using jsfl. I saw this link [Accessing child/nested movie clips with JSFL AS3 CS5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520652/accessing-child-nested-movie-clips-with-jsfl-as3-cs5-5) 
and based on that I wrote this code.

```
fl.outputPanel.clear();
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var tl = dom.getTimeline();
var curFrame = tl.currentFrame;
var curLayer = tl.findLayerIndex('Layer 2');

tl.setSelectedFrames(curFrame,curFrame);
dom.selection = [tl.layers[curLayer].frames[curFrame]];
//dom.enterEditMode('inPlace');

var tle = dom.timelines[0];
var elm = tle.layers[curLayer].frames[curFrame].elements[0];
var lt = elm.libraryItem;
var ctl = lt.tle;//????
fl.trace(ctl.layers[curLayer].frames[curFrame].elements);
```

now i guess i must have bundled something because i get this 'typeerror: ctl has no properties'. 
[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i4Fx.jpg)
pls help me with suggestions on how to achieve what i want. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you set `var tle=dom.timelines[0];` you are saying, in effect, "Let me use `tle` in place of `dom.timelines[0]` from now on."

So the error message is telling you that this thing doesn't exist: `dom.timelines[0].layers[curLayer].frames[curFrame].elements[0].libraryItem.tle`

Which is correct. `libraryItem` is an object of type [SymbolItem], and SymbolItems don't have children named `tle`. Though they do have a child named `timeline`, which is likely what you want.

Also, the last `trace` statement won't mean what you expect because you're in the `ctl` timeline and not the `tl` timeline.  For testing you may want to start with `fl.trace(ctl.layers[0].frames[0].elements);`

The reference document is here:
https://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/flash/cs5/flash_cs5_extending.pdf